# how to remove "public" from url

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-blade

**hi everyone,**

I want to deploy my Laravel project to production. the "public" not removing in base URL.

**I have tried this solution:**

1. rename server.php to index.php
2. cut .htaccess from */public* and paste to root

it works but CSS, JS, images not loading.

if anyone knows about this problem please share your knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: There is a reason there is a `public` folder. It's to make sure that no request have access to any PHP files directly (other than index.php). So a safe solution would be to simply config the web server to use the public folder as document root instead (as it was intended).

Comment: why do you want to remove the public folder any specific reason that you cannot deploy your app due to index.php being loaded inside from the public folder? Why don't you use a default configuration and point your webserver to the public directory?

Comment: Well there is no need to remove the public from the url, you can simply point your domain to public folder to achieve this. Even I deploy my app same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not found any solution,

I have configured the base Url with the public word in the apache Vhost configuration.

in this way, my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `.htaccess` file in your public_html (or your domain root folder). Edit the file & add the following code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Save it and do a test. You should able to access your Laravel public folder via domain.com. Keep in mind that you might have to clear your browser cache.

Comment: It doesn't require to rename server.php or moving .htaccess file from root to public folder. Keep original settings as it is and try to alter root .htaccess file with above script.

Comment: karthick please have a look above answer, I have added result after applied your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

karthick, the result after applied your suggested .htaccess code
[image]